# systemd: Start another unit when unit exits

Tags: systemd

Say I have a unit `foo.service` that I want run after `bar.service` exits (with any status, whether success or failure). I do not think that `After=` or `Before=` will help me here. How can I accomplish this within systemd and not in the script launched by systemd?

For context, in my environment, say `bar.service` fails and has a line `OnFailure=foo.service` to force `foo.service` to fix problems and then launch `bar.service` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (probably) use [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=)

> Additional commands that are executed after the service is stopped.
>   This includes cases where the commands configured in `ExecStop=` were
>   used, where the service does not have any `ExecStop=` defined, or where
>   the service exited unexpectedly. This argument takes multiple command
>   lines, following the same scheme as described for `ExecStart=`. Use of
>   these settings is optional. Specifier and environment variable
>   substitution is supported. Note that – unlike `ExecStop=` – commands
>   specified with this setting are invoked when a service failed to start
>   up correctly and is shut down again.
>
> It is recommended to use this setting for clean-up operations that
>   shall be executed even when the service failed to start up correctly.
>   Commands configured with this setting need to be able to operate even
>   if the service failed starting up half-way and left incompletely
>   initialized data around. As the service's processes have been
>   terminated already when the commands specified with this setting are
>   executed they should not attempt to communicate with them.
>
> Note that all commands that are configured with this setting are
>   invoked with the result code of the service, as well as the main
>   process' exit code and status, set in the `$SERVICE_RESULT`, `$EXIT_CODE`
>   and `$EXIT_STATUS` environment variables, see [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#) for
>   details.

Comment: I'll try it....

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. I had it call a script and I cannot see any evidence that it ran.

Comment: I take it back, I forgot a `daemon-reload`.